# Do you need to createEntityManager() everytime you are accessing your db?

Tags: java, entitymanager

If you are exercising CRUD procedures do you have to do this (with transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL not JTA)

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="mongo")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

EntityManager em;


@Inject
private SomeObj injectableObj;

public void create()
{
   em = emf.createEntityManager(); <---- here
   SomeObj obj = new SomeObj();
   em.persist(obj);
}

public void read()
{
   em = emf.createEntityManager();  <---- here
   Query query = em.createQuery("Select s from SomeObj s");

}

public void update()
{
   em = emf.createEntityManager();  <---- here
   SomeObj s = em.find(SomeObj.class, injectableObj.getId());
   s.setSomeObj(injectableObj.getSomeObj());

}

public void delete()
{

   em = emf.createEntityManager();  <---- here
   SomeObj s = em.find(SomeObj.class, injectableObj.getId());
   em.remove(s);
}
```

Question: Is there anyway to inject the EntityManager?

Comment: you need to use ThreadLocal for such kind of tasks. Please take a look here http://www.naildrivin5.com/daveblog5000/?p=39 and here http://javanotepad.blogspot.com/2007/08/managing-jpa-entitymanager-lifecycle.html - that's give more implementation details

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to look here for exemples :

[Injections EntityManager](http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-entitymanager/)

I prefer to use : Injection via `@PersistenceContext`

Comment: This is a NoSQL database. transaction type is RESOURCE_LOCAL NOT JTA. This being said, you cannot use PersistencContext and inject the entitymanager.

Answer (score 0):

You can use injection. I use it like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "some_jndi_name")
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: This is a NoSQL database (as denoted by unit_name="mongo"). transaction type is RESOURCE_LOCAL NOT JTA. This being said, you cannot use PersistencContext and inject the entitymanager

Comment: That's fine, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience in NoSQL databases